I have an image data when I add a new image data it appears as Null
This is my React.js passing data correctly:
 const[file ,setFile] = useState(null);
 const handleFileChange = (e) =>{
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            setFile(fileURL);
            setProductData(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                hinh_anh: file
            }));
        }
    }
return(
<div>
  <label>Hình Ảnh</label>
  <input type='file' className='form-control'  onChange={handleFileChange}/>
  {file && <img src={file} alt="Preview" width="100"  className='mt-2'/>}
</div>
 {
<td><img src={`http://localhost:8081/uploads/${product.hinh_anh}`} alt='Product' width={100}/></td>
 }
)


How can I fix the newly added image will be displayed not null?

Is this link okay?
{`http://localhost:8081/uploads/${product.hinh_anh}`}




Do you mean that product.hinh_anh can be null sometimes, and you want to show a different image when that happens?
